# What's the correct way to install YouComplete using vim-plug in vim/nvim?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-vim-plug

The only documentation for installing YCM seems to be for Vundle and I'm fairly new to vim-plug and plugins in general so I'm not sure how well it translates to vim-plug.

Comment: neovim didn't install it, vim-plug did. Where you told it to!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

neovim version 0.1 has breaking changes.   It uses directory `~/.config/nvim`
(On Mac OS X. Linux or Windows may use slightly different paths.)

If you want your neovim configuration independent of vim configuration, 
you can rename `.nvimrc` to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` (See the docs [here](https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-configuration) and [here](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_from_vim.html)).

Install vim-plug to `~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim`
The directory tree looks like this:

```
.config
├── nvim
    ├── autoload
    │   └── plug.vim
    ├── init.vim
    └── plugged
        ├── YouCompleteMe
        ├── ctrlp.vim
```

In neovim when you run `:PlugInstall`, vim-plug will install your plugins to the path you specified in `init.vim`
Use `.config/nvim/plugged`

```
" for vim
" call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
" for neovim
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
" Keep Plug commands between plug#begin/end.
Plug 'https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

If you want neovim to use vim's plugin location, replace directory `.config/nvim` with a symlink named `.config/nvim` that points to `.vim`

```
ln -s ~/.vim ~/.config/nvim
```

In .vim either add `init.vim` similar to `.vimrc`, or add symlink named `init.vim` to point to `.vimrc`

```
ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.vim/init.vim
```

In .vimrc

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```

If you use Homebrew to install neovim, at the end of the install it provides some helpful info about setting the symlinks: https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim

Also many people create a git repo in a directory named "dotfiles" or similar to version control configuration files like `init.vim` and `.vimrc`. In other directories add symlinks to your dotfiles
(e.g. `~/.config/neovim/init.vim` could be symlinked to `~/dotfiles/init.vim`)
This is handy when setting up a new machine.

### YouCompleteMe

As warsong mentioned

```
pip install neovim
```

For C family language completion:

```
cd ~/.config/nvim/plugged/YouCompleteMe
./install.py
```

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe

I ran `install.py` separately, hadn't seen nifty one-liner method

```
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py' }
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to install it.

What I did was install python for neovim using

```
pip install neovim
```

The next thing I did was

```
:PlugInstall YouCompleteMe
```

from within neovim and it started installing as it normally does (if you have all the usual YCM dependencies installed).

My .nvimrc still had the section for YCM in it and I guess vim-plug still uses those.

Edit:
I don't understand why YCM gets installed to the old vim plugins folder (/.vim) instead of neovim's folder (well I do, because I specified it, but shouldn't neovim install plugins to it's own folder structure? I thought it would be smart enough..) Is it even a good idea to be sharing folder hierarchies like that?

This is what I had in my .nvimrc

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Make sure you use single quotes
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py' }

call plug#end()
```

Answer (score 4):

It's installed in the .vim/ dir, because of

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```

try:

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
```

Instead, as answered above