# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylama'

Tags: vimrc, plugin-python-mode

I am taking errors whenever open python code and then press a movement key. Just only have these error in `.py` extensions. Even not in the `pyc`

```bash
 Error detected while processing CursorMoved Autocommands for "<buffer=1>"..script /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/pymode/lint.vim:
line    1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing CursorMoved Autocommands for "<buffer=1>"..script /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/pymode/lint.vim:
line    1:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing CursorMoved Autocommands for "<buffer=1>"..script /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/pymode/lint.vim:
line    1:
  File "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/pymode/lint.py", line 9, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing CursorMoved Autocommands for "<buffer=1>"..script /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/pymode/lint.vim:
line    1:
    from pylama.lint.extensions import LINTERS
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing CursorMoved Autocommands for "<buffer=1>"..script /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/pymode/lint.vim:
line    1:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylama'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm able to fix this error partially with adding **pymode plug-in**. No longer vim doesn't give errors.

`Plug 'python-mode/python-mode', { 'for': 'python', 'branch': 'develop' }`

However whenever press  <kbd>J</kbd> or any movement key first time then it is freezing a moment(maybe a second).

I think my solution is't good enough? Is there any reliable solution?

My plugins

```
Plug 'prabirshrestha/vim-lsp'
Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'
Plug 'jremmen/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plug 'vim-utils/vim-man'
Plug 'lyuts/vim-rtags'
Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
"Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
Plug 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'webastien/vim-ctags'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim',{'branch':'release'}
Plug 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plug 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plug 'python-mode/python-mode', { 'for': 'python', 'branch': 'develop' }
```

Comment: I suppose you have two problems of different kinds. The first seems to be that the initial version of python-mode installed your machine rely on ``pylama`` that is probably not available on your machine (at least for the interpreter used by the plugin). The second is probably that one of your plugin install a mapping that starts with ``J`` maybe could you figure out which one using the following command: ``:verbose map <S-j>``

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt You right, I've different problems. But couldn't detect precisely. I removed *vim-lsp* and *coc* then added YCM that got rid of these errors and freezing problem. I'll try more optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode#:%7E:text=From%202017%2D11%2D19%20onwards%20python%2Dmode%20uses%20submodules%20instead%20of%20hard%20coding%203rd%20party%20libraries%20into%20its%20codebase.%20Please%20issue%20the%20command%3A%20git%20submodule%20update%20%2D%2Dinit%20%2D%2Drecursive%20inside%20your%20python%2Dmode%20folder.) on the official page of Python-mode,

> From 2017-11-19 onwards python-mode uses submodules instead of hard coding 3rd party libraries into its codebase. Please issue the command: git submodule update --init --recursive inside your python-mode folder.

Then you can address this issue by cloning its submodules(like the following):

```
cd /Users/lernerzhang/.local/share/nvim/plugged/
mv python-mode python-mode_bp
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode.git
```

A better approach to solving the auto-completion problem is to utilize YouCompleteMe. One solution can be found [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5413/1788).